# unable to connect to VPN (just since a couple of days ago)

Tags: vpn, youtube, tor, web-filtering, hotspot-shield

Have had no problem connecting to filtered websites till a couple of days ago.
I usually use psiphon3 and it doesn't work now, tested Hotspot shield and it didn't work either, although I was able to connect using TOR but it's too slow to watch youtube! ;)

By the way, I have no problem connecting to the internet itself as I'm actually writing this on my laptop. My OS is Windwos 10 Education and I have a ESET 10 Antivirus installed. And internet flows through a hotspot(on my phone)

---

I SHOULD REPEAT I DIDN'T HAVE ANY PROBLEMS BEFORE!
this problem is at most a couple of days old!

Comment: Check your firewall and virusscanner. Virusscanners sometimes have firewall modules in them. Disable the firewalls and check again. If it now works, find out how to make an exclusion in your firewall to allow VPN traffic.

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 0):

Since when you have the Antivirus installed on your computer? Security software like ESET 10 are known to making trouble when you are using VPN, especially Tor.

You can disable your antivir and then it should work or trying to whitelist it as [here](https://support.eset.com/kb2769/) explained, when you don't want to waive your ESET 10!